# Dynamically reconfiguring parameters from other nodes

Tags: ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

So, I'm running `nodeA` with a dynamic_reconfigure server, that's working just fine. I'm using `rqt_reconfigure` and everything's ok. Now I have a new node, `nodeB`, from where I want to modify parameters in `nodeA`. I've figured out there are 2 topics: `/nodeA/parameter_descriptions[dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]` and `/nodeA/parameter_updates[dynamic_reconfigure/Config]`. So, I've created a publisher that complies with that interface and now I'm publishing to that topic. I can publish exactly what I want to the updates topic (if I echo it, I get the values I want for each parameter), but the callback that should be called in `nodeA` is not getting called, ergo ignoring the updates. It's important to say that this callback works just fine when modifying parameters using `rqt_reconfigure`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299796/dynamically-reconfiguring-parameters-from-other-nodes/) by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dynamic reconfigure clients use a service interface, the topics are just for feedback.  Take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/UsingTheDynamicReconfigurePythonClient and #q12276 .

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on 2018-08-06**:
I love you